# Javascript keeps saying Google is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the example code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml (with a few modifications, like lat/long) but every time I try to run it, it says google is undefined.
As a programmer, I'm pretty green-how do I fix it/prevent it, and what does it mean?

Comment: Is the script loaded before your code runs? Make sure that order of scripts is correct.

Comment: Did u included required Javascripts?

Comment: This is telling you that 'google' <- the object you are trying to initalize, does not exist in the current context. Undefined is a special term in Javascript meaning "I can't find anything matching the call you are making" As the others have pointed out here, check to make sure you are including all the necessary javascript files from Google in your page BEFORE calling this script to ensure that the class gets defined before you try to initialize it with the call in the tutorial. (Also people will help more if you put the tutorial code here instead of linking to it!)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is, you need to get Goggle's API first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
...
<script>
    /* Code Here */
</script>
```

[Look here for how to get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) in the developers guide.

If you look at the HTML+JavaScript notice they included the API at the top:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link you sent, there's a section called "Getting Started":
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

In there you will find out that a basic structure of a HTML page that is going to work with the API functionalities needs a declaration of the Javascript containing the API code (i.e., this code will also provide this 'google' object that you need).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
```